# How to define a ticket of ten in Schema.org "PriceSpecification"?

Tags: schema.org

I try to get our pricing into the `PriceSpecification` scheme from Schema.org.

For our time based tickets this is pretty straight forward, like for our 3-month ticket:

```json
    "priceSpecification": {
        "@type": "UnitPriceSpecification",
        "priceCurrency": "USD",
        "price": "10",
        "referenceQuantity": {
            "@type": "QuantitativeValue",
            "value": "3",
            "unitCode": "MON"
        }
    },
```

But we also have a "ticket of 10", which I try to describe, if possible with a `unitCode` and not a `unitText`.

Is there any UNECE/CEFACT code for this to describe or do I have to use `unitText` as fallback?

Comment: Are you sure that your use of `eligibleQuantity` is appropriate? As far as I understand it, it’s for specifying how many items can be ordered for this price. So for example, it could be used if you offer 3-month tickets for 9 USD (instead of 10) if someone orders more than 5.

Comment: Ah sorry, copied wrong snipped, will update

Comment: In case you’re not aware: `referenceQuantity` is defined for `UnitPriceSpecification`, not for `PriceSpecification`.

Comment: Do you have an own `Offer` for each kind of ticket?

Comment: Ah, copy&paste ftw :) Will correct this. Have not checked Offer specification yet. The monthly and yearly tickets are UnitPriceSpecifications only at the moment, without Offer. By the way offtopic question, how can I hightlight field names, like you do?

Comment: It’s the markup for inline code: by enclosing it in `\``, so: `\`code\``